# How to define Rails Helper for one specific action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, helper

I have a LabelTagHelper with a custom `label_tag` method, but I only need this method in my **new**, **create**, **edit** and **update** actions.

Is there a way to define this helper only for a specific action? Something like `helper :label_tag, :only => [:new, :create, :update, :destroy]`? Or it is safe to call `self.class.helper :label_tag` in a before_filter?

Answer (score 1):

rails Helpers should be just formatters. Think of it just as functions that will decorate your presentation layer (view)

So having helpers as :before_filter doesn't make any sense. As controllers actions often involves some server side processing.

So call your helper as and when you want. So there is no need to add helpers only for a specific action. as I mentioned earlier helpers and controller/ model actions should be mutually exclusive

BTW, could you elaborate your requirement, why you want to restrict your helper

HTH

sameera

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstood me. In my **index** view I want to use the built-in `label_tag` but for the other actions I want to use my own helper which overwrites the built-in `label_tag`. And no, I'm not going to rename my helper. ;)

Comment: Ah... ok now I understand your question... I'll also try out a way. meanwhile if you find a solution pls post it here sorry.. :D

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Have a helper method like this (in my case i used a helper called 'ProjectsHelper')

```
module ProjectsHelper
  def label_tag *params
    if controller.action_name == "index"
      #user custom implementation
    else
      super
    end

  end
end
```

This is working... hope this is what you need,

cheers

HTH

sameera

NOTE: sorry for not updating the existing answer. Since this is completely new approach thought of having it as a separate answer